# nuxt content markdown page using my own components?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to create my own blog page using nuxt content for the benefits of static site generation. On styling i used tailwindcss so i made my own components to reuse the css styles on the whole page.

When i tried to add them to a nuxt content markdown page in the documentation it states that the used component should be registerd global and i think there i fail somehow.

I've created a blank project to recreate the problem using

```
npx nuxi init content-blog -t content
```

i used

```
"@nuxt/content": "^2.4.3",
"nuxt": "^3.2.2"
```

but newer versions resulted in the same issue

and added the following component to the directory
*~/components/at/home*

```
<template>
    It Worked!
    <h1>
        <ContentSlot :use="$slots.default" unwrap="p" />
    </h1>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
    },
  }
</script>
```

in the generated *index.md* i've added at the bottom

```
::at-home-h1
YES
::
```

To register the component globaly i've added a plugin in the directory *~/plugins*

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { AtHomeH1 } from '~/components/at/home/h1.vue'
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const app = createApp({})
    app.component('AtHomeH1', AtHomeH1)
})
```

and registerd it in the *nuxt.config.ts*

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['@nuxt/content'],
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/component2content.js' }
  ]
})
```

but on executing nuxt and watching the source of the site i see:

```
<at-home-h1><p><!--[-->YES<!--]--></p></at-home-h1>
```

and get the warning in the command line

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: at-home-h1
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: AtHomeH1
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

i've also tried to add *components: true* in the *nuxt.config.ts* without success

See the complete source executable on https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-uzn4hz

I would be grateful for hints on solving this and/or even a more elegant solution on how to match the markdown transformation to my own components / tailwindcss.

Otherwise i've to put the whole md content within a div and format it in the good old css way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The component must be located in `~/components/content/...` or you can add it manually to `nuxt.config`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).